# How to skip completion handler in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have one function which return Int value in completion handler, however sometimes, I want to skip completion handler while calling from other class and just have Int value. Below is my code. Here totalEvents is with completion handler.

Like I need to call below method

```
let initialDBCount = self.totalEvents()

func totalEvents(completion: @escaping (_ eventsCount: Int? ) -> Void ) {

    self.fetchEvents(forPredicate: nil, withSort: nil, andLimit: nil, completion: { (events) -> Void in
        guard let fetchEvents = events else {
            return
        }
        if fetchEvents.count > 0 {
            completion(fetchEvents.count)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by skip exactly?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to have the int value? Maybe you could give an example of how the function would be without any completion handler at all

Comment: Okay, suppose I directly need to fetch events. Then I would call let fetchCount = self. totalEvents()

Comment: Unrelated but `(_ eventsCount: Int? ) -> Void` is legacy Swift 2 code. The parameter label is not used at all. The Swift 3+ syntax is  `(Int?) -> Void`. And your call `let initialDBCount = self.totalEvents()` cannot work as `totalEvents has no return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `completion` handler as *optional* and set `nil` as its *default value*, i.e.

```
func totalEvents(completion: ((_ eventsCount: Int?)->())? = nil)
```

**Usage:**

`totalEvents` can be called in both the ways,

**1.** Without `completion` handler

```
totalEvents()
```

**2.** With `completion` handler

```
totalEvents { (value) in
    print(value)
}
```

Comment: @escaping attribute only applies to function types. I think you can check in Xcode by typing same function

Comment: @Kashif Remove `@escaping` attribute.

Comment: func totalEvents(completion: ((_ eventsCount: Int?)->())? = nil) {
      
    }
This will be correct way, thanks for all suport

Answer (score 0):

Make optional the completion (_eventsCount: Int?) -> () )? = nil or call the completion like

```
  if fetchEvents.count > 0 {
    completion(fetchEvents.count)
  }
```